# Symfony Route Doesn't Show in debug:router

Tags: symfony, routes

I can't for the life of me get this route to work:

```
/***
 * @Route("/load_base_data/{projectId}", name="load_base_data", methods={"GET"})
 * @return Response
 */
public function loadBaseMeasures(int $projectId, DataLoadService $dataLoadService, ApiService $apiService)
{
    $response = $apiService->initResponse();
    $dataLoadService->generateFiles($projectId);

    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

I've tried php bin/console debug:router and it doesn't show up on the list.
I've tried php bin/console cache:clear

This is the only route I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Just a guess and I'm too lazy to test it myself but change /*** to /** and see if that helps.  I am assuming this is in a controller and that other controller routes are showing up.

Comment: does it need to be `loadBaseMeasuresAction` ?

Comment: @craigh No, the Action suffix is not needed.  Back in S2 it was used when defining routes in yaml/xml files.  But it is no longer a thing.

Comment: routes can be overridden by other routes with the exact same **name** (literally the `name` attribute in the annotation), removing the former route in favour of the latter. can you check that this route has a unique name?

Comment: Try `bin/console router:match /load_base_data/123` and see if it matches. This would tell you a near match and if it is overwritten. Also check your routing.yaml if you even included this controller and activated annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Cerad was right, the problem was the `/***`. Changed to `/**` and it worked. Thanks!